# iOS - How to code a DecodeHelper Class in Swift with Generics?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, decodable

I am trying to create my own DecodeHelper class.

Here is where I am struggling :

```
final class DecodeHelper {

    static func myDecodeMethod<T>(data: Data, completion : (Result<T, ErrorResult>) -> Void) {

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Forecast.self, from: data)
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        } catch {
            completion(Result.failure(.decoder(string: "Error while decoding json data")))
        }
    }
}
```

This method will be called in the switch (success case only) after receiving the data from Backend.

But I don't know how to code it in a generic way. Should I pass the expected type as a parameter (Forecast.self here) ?

This is not compiling :

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Result<Forecast, _>' to expected argument type 'Result<_, ErrorResult>'
```

Any advices are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to add the requirement that `T` is `Decodable`…

```
final class DecodeHelper {

    static func myDecodeMethod<T: Decodable>(data: Data, completion : (Result<T, ErrorResult>) -> Void) {

        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(Result.success(decodedData))
        } catch {
            completion(Result.failure(.decoder(string: "Error while decoding json data")))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it was exactly what I needed.

Comment: You should ask this as another question